M301 command no response on Monoprice Select
I am trying to implement new PID values to try and solve a heat creep issue. The Marlin command M301 and M304 do not get a response (example code below). M104, M503, and M303 all work. When I use M503 to view the current PID values, they also haven't changed. I am using a Monoprice Select Printer and Pronterface to communicate.
>>> M301 P20 I0.02 D250
SENDING:M301 P20 I0.02 D250
>>> M301
SENDING:M301
>>> M503
SENDING:M503
EPR:2 75 115200 Baudrate
EPR:3 129 2822.120 Filament printed [m]
EPR:2 125 2200571 Printer active [s]
EPR:2 79 0 Max. inactive time [ms,0=off]
EPR:2 83 360000 Stop stepper after inactivity [ms,0=off]
EPR:3 3 80.0000 X-axis steps per mm
EPR:3 7 80.0000 Y-axis steps per mm
EPR:3 11 405.4591 Z-axis steps per mm
EPR:3 15 200.000 X-axis max. feedrate [mm/s]
EPR:3 19 200.000 Y-axis max. feedrate [mm/s]
EPR:3 23 2.000 Z-axis max. feedrate [mm/s]
EPR:3 27 40.000 X-axis homing feedrate [mm/s]
EPR:3 31 40.000 Y-axis homing feedrate [mm/s]
EPR:3 35 2.000 Z-axis homing feedrate [mm/s]
EPR:3 39 20.000 Max. jerk [mm/s]
EPR:3 47 0.300 Max. Z-jerk [mm/s]
EPR:3 133 0.000 X home pos [mm]
EPR:3 137 0.000 Y home pos [mm]
EPR:3 141 0.000 Z home pos [mm]
EPR:3 145 200.000 X max length [mm]
EPR:3 149 200.000 Y max length [mm]
EPR:3 153 180.000 Z max length [mm]
EPR:3 51 1000.000 X-axis acceleration [mm/s^2]
EPR:3 55 1000.000 Y-axis acceleration [mm/s^2]
EPR:3 59 100.000 Z-axis acceleration [mm/s^2]
EPR:3 63 1000.000 X-axis travel acceleration [mm/s^2]
EPR:3 67 1000.000 Y-axis travel acceleration [mm/s^2]
EPR:3 71 100.000 Z-axis travel acceleration [mm/s^2]
EPR:0 880 0 Autolevel active (1/0)
EPR:0 106 0 Bed Heat Manager [0-3]
EPR:0 107 255 Bed PID drive max
EPR:0 124 80 Bed PID drive min
EPR:3 108 196.000 Bed PID P-gain
EPR:3 112 33.000 Bed PID I-gain
EPR:3 116 290.000 Bed PID D-gain
EPR:0 120 255 Bed PID max value [0-255]
EPR:3 200 96.000 Extr.1 steps per mm
EPR:3 204 50.000 Extr.1 max. feedrate [mm/s]
EPR:3 208 20.000 Extr.1 start feedrate [mm/s]
EPR:3 212 5000.000 Extr.1 acceleration [mm/s^2]
EPR:0 216 0 Extr.1 heat manager [0-3]
EPR:0 217 230 Extr.1 PID drive max
EPR:0 245 40 Extr.1 PID drive min
EPR:3 218 7.0000 Extr.1 PID P-gain/dead-time
EPR:3 222 2.0000 Extr.1 PID I-gain
EPR:3 226 40.0000 Extr.1 PID D-gain
EPR:0 230 255 Extr.1 PID max value [0-255]
EPR:2 231 0 Extr.1 X-offset [steps]
EPR:2 235 0 Extr.1 Y-offset [steps]
EPR:1 239 1 Extr.1 temp. stabilize time [s]
EPR:1 250 150 Extr.1 temp. for retraction when heating [C]
EPR:1 252 0 Extr.1 distance to retract when heating [mm]
EPR:0 254 255 Extr.1 extruder cooler speed [0-255]


What makes you think that a different PID schedule will give better heat creep resistance? As far as I know there is no link between PID and heat creep, unless you overshoot 40-50 °C or do. Heat creep is mostly related to too high print temperatures, printing speed and retraction length.

According to the description to use M301, the heater number needs to be included,
M301 P20 I0.02 D250

should therefore be:
M301 H1 P20 I0.02 D250


Parameters
Hnnn heater number (Smoothie uses 'S', Redeem uses 'E')
Pnnn proportional (Kp)
Innn integral (Ki)
Dnnn derivative (Kd)
Examples
M301 H1 P1 I2 D3 ; Marlin, RepRapFirmware

